# Illegal instruction (core dumped) when loading HDF

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, ubuntu

I have recently installed Anacondas Python on Lubuntu.

I am trying to load a HDF file that works on a Windows PC:

```
In [14]: import pandas as pd

In [15]: fn = '/home/jon/data/data.h5'

In [16]: store=pd.io.pytables.HDFStore( fn )
```

Unfortunately, running the above results in this error:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

How can I resolve this error? I do no know how to view the core dump.

My pandas version is 0.16.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found if I downgrade my pytables to 3.1.1. It works fine. Maybe you can give it a try.